# MySQL: can I use one table as a pattern for other tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

My question is, if its possible to design DB in a way, that a group of tables will have same table structure (but own data) as defined table (pattern table).

If I do any structural change in the pattern table, other tables referencing to it will apply same change.

#### Use case:

I want to prepare application, which will have by default one table called **items** with columns **id** and **type**. But, because it could be later quite huge table, I want to create clone of this table according to type, for example **items_pages**.

What I want to achieve by this design is, that I will not care of structure of those clones (they can be created dynamically by App), only maintain structural changes in **items** table, and all other will adopt these changes automatically.

Thx for any feedback

Comment: No it is not. That is not how a relational database works. Also you will usually want to put things with the same structure (entity) in the same table. You might have an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, so maybe describe the problem you want to solve, and we could provide a different idea to solve it, maybe an "is-a" relationship, which is a little bit similar to inheritance in oop.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question by example use case.

Comment: The reason WHY you want to do this is still not clear, there might be another way to achieve your actual goal. Generally: a table in a relational database has a fixed structure, and queries on that structure have to know that structure (there is e.g. no sql code for "4th column of a table", but you have to know the column names). You might want to have a look in "is-a", it could be use for what you are describing, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928272/database-is-a-relationship): one table with a type and common columns, and a table for each type with specialized columns.

Comment: I would say, that answer to WHY is that I wanted to play with table structure easily for multiple same kind of tables with items and in same time avoid problem of big size of this table.<br>

But solution could be as you (@Solarflare) probably try to propose is, that I will create one extra type of table called **items_values_pages**, columns:
item_id - link to **items** table
name - name of "column" for the item
value - value of column for item

where unique key would be (item_id, name)

Comment: It can decrease needs to update table structure to minimum and i can distribute amount of data into multiple tables according to type.

Comment: No, I actually didn't propose this. You are describing now an EAV-model (entity-attribute-value). I meant something like: table `person (id, name, birthday, ..., type)` (common for all persons) and specialized tables like e.g. `person_teacher (id, salery, department)` and `person_student (id, field, master, registration_number)`. EAV can make sense if you e.g. have several item types, all with different attributes; but it's not the fastest way, nor comfortable (e.g. joins or AND-filtering). There are many models, but without knowing more about what you are trying to do, it's hard to guide you.

Comment: Generally: the more dynamic you want to be, the slower and more complicated it gets. A relational database thrives on structure. It often seems hard to find the right data model for a specific problem, but it is usually rewarded. You can often generalize or simplify things. And you should also think about how you use it. It might sound nice to save as many information as you can about a product, but if you cannot use them because they are, well, unstructured, they are worthless (e.g. one might save a shoesize attribute as "size", "shoe size", "shoesize", and in inch, cm, uk, us or eu-norm).

Comment: It is _usually_ poor design to have two table with identical structure.  See `CREATE TABLE a LIKE b`

Comment: @Solarflare you were right about XY problem. I think EAV model is very close to something, what I am looking for. However, I have to solve, how to improve **EAV**, that also **A**ttributes could be **E**ntities. I dont necessary need comfortable or fast solution, but scallable one, which can handle complexity of my App (very abstract kick-off CMS lets say). Later I will focus on performance, this I can do via extra tables of course - but it will be another story.